# Learning effective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning, learning

today I got my midterm test result of Discrete math (It can only raise the grade). I got 63, which is above the average, but still I don't feel comfortable with that.
I have 7 courses in the semester, and the time management is pretty hard, because everything is time consuming.

I understand that I need to change things and how I learn, at least in Discrete math.
I notice I spend a lot of time reviewing what I do in class, and then going to the HW they gave us (but we don't get really a review on the HW) .I would glad for advices from experience people, how to understand what I need to improve or change, also does reviewing what I did in class in detail is a right thing? or is it better to try solve more problems or maybe look at books.
What helped you in improving your grades, and to success, and how to ease learning in hard courses and little time.

Thank you

Comment: I dont think that here is the right place to ask this question. It is nearly impossible to tell you how to learn. I think the main problem is the "7 courses" thing. It is just to much to really have the time to understand everything well, paired with the fact that understanding something well simply takes a lot of time and practice. Asking for advice from people from the internet is in my opinion a very risky buisness, because it might raise some toxic standards, where you only learn to disappoint yourself, or get some "fake guru" life advice. My advice is: Try to have fun with the material.

Comment: You cannot learn to do mathematics problems without doing problems. There are no shortcuts. Little time $\to$ little effort $\to$ little grade.

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat personal, as there is no guaranteed method for raising your grades; however, I could suggest a couple of things that helped with mine,

1. Printing stuff instead of viewing them online. This might be something that only I struggled with, but before my first midterms, I used to study by viewing everything online(i.e., homework, midterm samples). I noticed that I am concentrating better on actual printed materials instead.
2. Start the hw as soon as you get it and try not to rely too much on problem-solving sessions or office hours. I don't mean don't attend them all together; I mean attend them only after you did your best solving the problems yourself and only need a little guidance here and there. Ideally, you should be able to solve 80-100% of the homework yourself so you can ensure that you truly grasped the new materials
3. Start preparing for exams(using samples or just redoing all the homework) far earlier than other students usually do(typically, they start one week prior). You can start two weeks before, hence get more time to ask questions to professors
4. Do ask any question you have!! Whether it's from homework or midterm samples don't leave any confusion
5. I personally tend to record important lectures, but not sure how beneficial it could be for you
6. Before the exam after you run out of exam samples to solve go and solve extra problems from the textbooks that are mentioned in the syllabus. You can even search for midterm samples from other universities of that subject

I hope there are some helpful advice here. Good luck with your studies!